# curl response data is truncated to 1060 characters from the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION callback function in C++ (EDIT: Infinite looping GET request)

Tags: c++, libcurl

We have a C++ wrapper around the latest libcurl.dll API, and we are initializing it as such

```
CURL* CCurl::InitCurl() 
{
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  // Construct the CURL handle
  CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
  
  // The callback for receiving the incoming data
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, RecvDataCbk);

  // The buffer where the incoming data is stored
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &msInBuff);

  return curl;
}
```

The data ALWAYS arrives at 1060 chars and I have tested in other tools and in browser, and the cookie login session token has to be around 1300-1500 chars in practice

```
size_t CCurl::RecvDataCbk(void* data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userStorage)
{
  size_t inSize = size * nmemb;
  std::string& storage = *static_cast<std::string*>(userStorage);
  storage.append(static_cast<char*>(data), inSize);

  return inSize;
}
```

The data is a json in this format

> {"token":"4BsWsQZLFwTyr0LndswTxJykCPo_1T1PCpY4kMHsXQVg5z3-ggvtvfan_vOk4-PpzM5V9hjuNe9tI4nBzTh_ir6_5s4xATbk5NiToMvDs05GwycXDG6_BTKmQp0Ls9nrEsardCB9toomIKb-XMoHq1PM2-__77EjQFpuSYS9-X4PGmvbkwdhEJfpC_kHnwN4dCDIi3TAlJcCtelM_3EGETWww2aQtPMQOdUmAkGafBrAuENEM_JjNC7vsJMm9iQnWyLIV0IQsO_DRO14Ouq7j5phY8Dst6PgO1xhu0OZSCnmwNDUJ0Qe66LvATBuDmAumPXd1WQ21Sbhr32PfgmDXFljdv0baLSZmNaGlGGiciiMJW7JMXozXYRPucjBPY1so4fsnvrkUVege24lRbkEG8b1ULGTBEF3bdZkzmiDO2_3I2nnmqcoi7ttwn6C0_umq5RQkk3R-7tG8O2XWcmLaVuHLq9p1aF9b53r_cwA4JDqUMIr0RGaGyBRuVFAyOByi85wDHmTKWlr57LJhlXqxSb1ykcDfgbxIf_HOuntutVmmNpAF6nG0lIYVtt8bIJpUFLiciJUMpRsYkZeqFpG43rHpj6bz8D5jVGR7BcEmu8sm-T5IV1sDEHsRbCzQyIfkIRE2smE1V9CB5cF089U5I5E4KXrRhggk0EXCi9R8-WZ4kLY6qMKSp4_kra7OQW-1SlCcNUVcVxu_GDI5HKcKsVqF3bduZpVhR7r9XpkF61A2HLDFK2CG7-KDKSq6nax5eArzrZX27tcvHZp99ylIe-7kGtOcpkDCSjK-lEJe3gnhy8tvG6fgam3IWB-TEZFpyLDuSTl4gWguUFlbZPCDhevgvOYTg6embvVpeKVD_42Thu3w13Zgwxc8OY0OPyVfNsNzl2kTbBqrMbS9todqSiWKxEzwT4ArkbHy1vIV3sq_KluwaExjHWeH7TD1e-gOQurmmTgVf-5hHMc1xWn_i9msog_euTaGnfNWuk_IyUjDcu4K8Lernt14-Indhv6mdpXjliIxn_u-RkUkWtRDA.."}

As you can see it truncates the data at the end using dot dot ("..") `-RkUkWtRDA.."}`

From my logging, the vars are inSize = 1060 size = 1 nmemb = 1060

---

Anyone has any ideas?

I probably have to configure curl differently.

Are there any SETOPT curl options I am missing?

For reference, accross our wrapper we have the following options set:

```
Set<CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE>("");
Set<CURLOPT_PROXY>(<ourproxy>);
Set<CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST>(<GET or POST set based on our request>);
Set<CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH>(CURLAUTH_BASIC);
Set<CURLOPT_MIMEPOST>(<our mime from curl_mime_init>);
Set<CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE>(size);
Set<CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS>(pData);
```

Been stuck troubleshooting this past week.

Comment: for reference, the token from the login json is exactly 1048 chars all the time

Comment: `libcurl` doesn't truncate received data, especially it doesn't cut data off in the middle. Look for an error on the server side.

Comment: Agreed. Especially since the JSON is being terminated property with `"}` and the `..` appears before that, so the problem is in the preparation of the JSON, not the transmission of it

Comment: OP here: apparently, my colleagues are able to handle the requests from curl on their end, EVEN IF the data is "truncated" as I say. So it is something else on my network end. The original premise is false, the JSON is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Finally found a fix

First off, the "truncated" data hypothesis is false, you can make requests with fixed data in our application.

Secondly, postman is a great tool, use it to debug. Fiddler is a great tool as well, to compare apples to apples and see the full text of the request.

Thirdly, the core issue was that the GET REQUEST HAD A BODY LEFTOVER FROM A LOGIN REQUEST.

Basically, the request was infinite looping and never finishing on server side because we had the user/pass inside the body, and the server no longer tolerated requests with a body for GET requests.

The fix was: Just EMPTY the libcurl object's body between requests, make sure you start with a clean HTTP request.